# Is there a way to chain Javascript functions without creating a new object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fluent, chaining

Imagine we have a Button element

```
const ourButton = document.getElementById("#theButton");
```

And we want a fluent API to change the styles of this button without creating a new object, so chain a function like this:

```
style(ourButton).property("padding").value("32px");
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to figure out how to create this behaviour. I tried building a Fluent API "the conventional way" by creating a constructor function like this:

```js
var FStyle = function(node) {
  this.node = node;
}

FStyle.prototype.property = function(property) {
  this.property = property;
  return this;
}

FStyle.prototype.value = function(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.node.style[this.property] = this.value;
  return this;
}
```

and using it by constructing a new object:

```js
const ourButtonStyle = new FStyle(ourButton);
ourButtonStyle.property("padding").value("64px");
```

Which works, once. If I would like to add a new style I have to create a whole new object. Why is this?

TL;DR: For learning purposes I'm trying to chain functions but don't understand it fully enough to understand the above behaviour. Returning this in a normal function to chain other functions to it won't do the job either. In the end **I would like to "pipe" the result of a function to an other function**.

Comment: Why does it work only once? It looks like `ourButtonStyle.property("foo").value("bar").property("baz").value("qux")` should work just fine. (Aside: stuff like `ourButtonStyle.property("foo").property("bar").value("baz")` is also possible, but confusing, which shows that this might not be the best API design.)

Comment: Just saying: there's absolutely nothing wrong with creating new objects!

Comment: @Thomas I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: ourButtonStyle.property is not a function" after executing the chain once. MRA: https://codepen.io/melvinidema/pen/wvKVNba?editors=0011

Comment: @Bergi I agree, but the point of why I'm trying to do this. (instead of just calling: `node.style.property = value` - which is way more minimalistic) is to practice method chaining and creating Fluent API's. And creating a new object every time you want to change a style isn't really practical IMO.

Comment: @MelvinIdema In an ideal fluent API, all objects are immutable, and each method call will return a new instance. (I'm not saying that you should have to call `new FStyle(…)` multiple times, I'm only saying that you could easily use multiple objects in the chain).

Comment: How would that look like within this context @Bergi ? I think I do understand you but I find it hard to create a practical example of it.

Comment: Possibly something like `return new FStyle(this.node, this.property, newValue)` instead of `this.value = newValue; return this`, although admittedly the whole thing doesn't make a lot sense in your particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not easily seen, the issue here is the namings!

You are creating a prototype function called `property` and then essentially you overwrite this function with the value you got from the function call. Check the comments in the code below.

```
FStyle.prototype.property = function(property) {
  // at this point "ourButtonStyle.property" is a function
  this.property = property;
  // here "ourButtonStyle.property" is a string 
  return this;
}
```

An easy fix would be to rename these with something slightly deifferent

```
var FStyle = function(node) {
  this.node = node;
}

FStyle.prototype.property = function(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;
  return this;
}

FStyle.prototype.value = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.node.style[this.prop] = this.val;
  return this;
}
```

Comment: This was a huge "Eureka" moment right here. You're absolutely right! Weird how this just completely went over my head. 

Sadly -and weirdly- though, it doesn't seem to solve the problem... I still get the typeError. But checking the type of ourButtonStyle.property it says: function. Even after executing it once. The console literally logs:

`Typeof ourButtonStyle.property: function` and immediatly after:
`typeError ourButtonStyle.property is not a function`

Comment: *Facepalm*, I didn't see you changed the value as well. Thank you so much! I think it's time for a break haha. Solved! Do you perhaps have a suggestion to chain functions without creating a new object? Something like: `changeStyle(node).property("border-color").value("red");`

Comment: @MelvinIdema Glad, you got it working! As for your question about chaining without creating directly a new object, maybe something like this could help you: `function changeStyle(node){ return new FStyle(node)}`